# Krunner equivalent in XFCE?

Tags: xfce

I like Krunner, but nowadays I prefer to use XFCE instead of KDE. Is there any XFCE app that is equivalent or similar to Krunner?

Answer (score 5):

gmrun, may be? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gmrun

Comment: +1 I use `gmrun` in LXDE (instead of `lxpanelctl run`), and it's great: list of completions and remember old commands.

Comment: No history with `xfce4-appfinder`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very old post, but anyway:

- **Whisker Menu** - the now default Xfce menu launcher, can find only applications (that is `.desktop` files created in `usr/local/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`), but not files & folders, like krunner can.
- **Synapse** - not Xfce-specific, but probably the best launcher anyway, at least for a gtk environment, meets up the `krunner` standards. To start it with just the Super key, follow [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/511236/925128)